# Using gitlab-runner locally and passing artifacts from previous step

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to debug some issues in my GitLab CI pipeline. I have a step B which is using some artifacts from step A.

Step A is very long (and is working in the CI), so I don't want to run it locally: I just download the resulting artifacts from GitLab. So I have an `artifacts.zip`, which I extracted to obtain an `output` and a `logs` directory. So far so good.

I want to run step B locally, using `gitlab-runner`. Note that I am using version 9.5 (https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/old.html).

I am using this command:

```
gitlab-runner exec docker step-b
```

As I explained, `step-b` needs the artifacts from `step-a`. This is what I tried:

```
gitlab-runner exec docker --docker-volumes ~/Downloads/output step-b
```

One of the script executed in step B is doing something like `mv ../output /some/where/else`. However, this script fails with the following error:

```
mv: cannot stat '../output': No such file or directory
```

Following this error, I have two questions:

- Where is this script executed? It's called like that from the `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

  ```
  ./scripts/my_script.sh.
  ```

  What is the `.` in this context?
- How can I make sure that using the `--docker-volumes ~/Downloads/output` will mount the directory in the right place so my script can find it?

**EDIT**

As requested, here is a description of step A.

```
script:
  - mkdir -p /usr/local/compil_result
  - ./scripts/compil.sh
  - mv /usr/local/compil_result ./output
artifacts:
  paths:
    - output
    - logs
```

Comment: Could you add `step-a` job definition from your `.gitlab-ci.yml` in your description ?

Comment: I made an edit to add it. I didn't put an exact copy/paste, but I think I put everything that could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not mentioned what docker image you use,  I assume it's a custom image you or your colleague have made. I think you need to check the Dockerfile of your docker image back, to make sure where the working directory of that script is.

Or you could also try to get inside the shell, and see the structure inside your container first,

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash your-image-name
```

To mount a Docker volume, you need to host  directory and container directory separated by  a colon, and use full path directory for both of them.

Something like this,

```
gitlab-runner exec docker --docker-volumes '/home/username/Downloads/output:/output' step-b
```